# How do I configure Spacy pipeline to lemmatize a spellchecker component's results?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

I'm currently trying to add a spellchecker step into one of Spacy's built-in pipelines, specifically `'en_core_web_sm'`

I found a pretty neat component called [Contextual Spell Check](https://spacy.io/universe/project/contextualSpellCheck) that I've inserted into the pipeline. The problem is that the lemmatize step isn't lemmatizing the spell-checked word, but rather the original text, EVEN after I've reordered the pipeline to `['tok2vec', 'parser', 'contextual spellchecker', 'tagger', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer', 'ner']`.

For example:

```
doc_a = nlp("Income wes $9.4 milion compared to the prior year of $2.7 milion.")
doc_b = nlp("Income was $9.4 milion compared to the prior year of $2.7 milion.")
```

Will return the correctly spell-checked results of:

```
print(doc_a._.outcome_spellCheck)
# Income was $9.4 million compared to the prior year of $2.7 million.

print(doc_b._.outcome_spellCheck)
# Income was $9.4 million compared to the prior year of $2.7 million.
```

However, examining the underlying results:

```
# doc_a with misspelled 'was'. Note lemma is still the original typo 'wes'
print(doc_a.to_json()['tokens'])
# {'id': 1, 'start': 7, 'end': 10, 'tag': 'MD', 'pos': 'AUX', 'morph': 'VerbType=Mod', 'lemma': 'wes', 'dep': 'ROOT', 'head': 1}

# doc_b with correctly spelled 'was'. Correctly lemmatized to 'be'
print(doc_b.to_json()['tokens'])
# {'id': 1, 'start': 7, 'end': 10, 'tag': 'VBD', 'pos': 'AUX', 'morph': 'Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Past|VerbForm=Fin', 'lemma': 'be', 'dep': 'ROOT', 'head': 1}
```

How do I ensure lemmatize happens on the spell-checked term?

Answer (score 1):

spaCy is designed to make sure that the original text is never modified. Unfortunately that is not what you want in your case, but there is not really a way to work around it.

In this case I would recommend you have a spellcheck-only pipeline, and use the spellchecker output to generate a new string that you feed to your lemmatizing pipeline.

Something like this...

```
spellchecker = ... minimal nlp with the spellchecker...
nlp = ... normal non-spellcheck pipeline ...

doc = nlp(spellchecker(text)._.outcome_spellCheck)
```

There are other things you could do like load the lemmatizer and create a component to feed spellchecker results to it directly, or maybe use an attribute ruler to map from spellchecker output to your tokens, but the separate pipelines is probably easier to set up as it has minimal dependencies between parts.

Comment: All great ideas. I'm new to Spacy so I'll see how far I can get with creating a new component off of an old one.